# Copying the staging farm inside my development environment

Tags: 2013, search-results, backup, restore, farm

We have three SharePoint server professional 2013environments; development, staging +live.

Now due to time limitation we did a lot of modifications and testing to our staging server directly without doing this inside the dev environment first.so now after we have deployed the applications live server, I want to have the three environment the same. Mainly I need to copy the whole farm from staging to development .

so can anyone advice on this , and what are the required steps to complete this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Their are couple of ways you can do it.

**Method # 1** ( i am assuming you have the same kind of web application)

- take the backup of content DBs from Stagging
- restore into Dev farm,
- Detach the Old DataBase from SharePoint Dev farm Web App and Attach the New DB(stagging)
- deploy any solutions if you have.
- Make any changes to Web .config(if any).

**Method # 2**

If you have made the SharePoint designer changes to your site collection and you want to move the single site collection.

- take the backup of site collection from stagging(wither Central Admin or pwoershell)
- Move the bak files to dev farm
- restore the site collection to required path using powershell.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but we have also added some metadata services, search services, etc. so i was thinking if i take a backup of the Farm from the staging and restore it inside the dev ? is this valid approach ?